# Apache do not redirect correctly. Two similar projects, but different redirect

Tags: 14.04, apache2, lamp, xampp, virtualhost

I've installed xampp, and started configuring my current working project, and as a result I was unable to do this due to magic circumstances. First of all I guessed that this is something wrong with xampp, but I decided to create simple virtual host to check how it works, and this virtual hosts works perfectly, but not my working project :(. So, I'll tell what I've done, and I would be very happy if someone will help me:

XAMPP is located in **/opt/lampp** 
Working and custom project in **/home/awesomeUser/dirForWork/projForWor**

1. Removed `#` from apache's `httpd.conf` to include virtual hosts
2. Created new virtual host in `httpd-vhosts.conf` and it looks like:

> ```
>     <VirtualHost *>
>         DocumentRoot "/home/awesomeUser/dirForWork/projForWor"
>         ServerName test.localistic
>         <Directory "/home/awesomeUser/dirForWork/projForWor">
>           Require all granted
>         </Directory>
>     </VirtualHost>
> ```

At **/home/awesomeUser/dirForWork/projForWor** I have `index.php` with `echo phpinfo();`

3. Added to `/etc/host  127.0.0.1 test.localistic`
4. Restarted xampp, and that's all, PROFIT!

But I've done the same actions for my working project and I just have the redirection to xampp's splash page. How it can be even possible? That splash project is on /opt and my request goes to /home... Share your thoughts about this

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I setup a vhost in Apache, but I think it should be more along the lines of

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/awesomeUser/dirForWork/projForWor
ServerName test.localistic
 <Directory /home/awesomeUser/dirForWork/projForWor> 
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

**Edit**

I don't think you need the "" in DocumentRoot and Directory

Also, did you remember to add index.php before index.html in

```
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

You could also add the vhost settings in my answer into /etc/apache2/sites-available and then symlink it to sites enabled, reload Apache and should work.

So as example, add my answer to a file (call whatever), but for sake of example we will call it work.conf

Then

```
 sudo a2ensite work.conf
```

And then

```
 sudo service apache2 reload
```

**Final Edit**

I don't use xampp, I just have a regular LAMP install.  I added my above answer (but tweaked to match my home directory) to /etc/apache2/sites-available/geoffmcc.conf

And then did

```
 sudo a2ensite geoffmcc.conf

 sudo service apache2 reload
```

Tweaked my domain name to accept and as you can see vhost works

[vhost](http://geoffmcc.digitaltrainwreck.com)

As opposed to the default site

[default](http://digitaltrainwreck.com)

Comment: adding 80 port did not help...

Comment: What about removing the "" from DocumentRoot and Directory?

Comment: @Boog see my updated answer. It shows how I did it, but a little different than you.

Comment: I suspect your way will work too (once you fix DocumentRoot and Directory line) I suspect you forgot to put index.php before index.html in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` so since it can't find index.html for whatever reason it hits the xampp default. Not sure why cause it in another directory, but I'm pretty sure that what going on. Either way you go, my answer should get you there.

Comment: removing "" also did not helped, and both vhosts works as earlier(that simple works and that what i really need don't)

Comment: I must have missed something, or it the fact that your using xampp and I'm using LAMP, as you can see by my links I got working. Did you check `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` you can even adjust my vhost url to /info.php and see php is also working

Comment: In both projects index is php file. Both project uses mutual vhosts configuration file, so I just removed my test vhost, and only one thing which changed is: prevoiusly, I saw xampp's splash page on url http://myProject.local, and now I see it on http://myProject.local/xampp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20741/discussion-between-boog-and-geoffmcc).